# Locating element in the dom with parent selenium xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to select a checkbox from table td element, but Selenium is not finding the element, this is my xpath locator `"//*/td/a[contains(.,'Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1')]//parent::td[last()]/input[@type='checkbox']"`. I need to click on input filed with type checkbox, depending on the text in the with the Galaxy text.

[image: Dom]

Comment: If I not accept an answer, maybe it was not solving my issue I will recheck the questions and will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this xpath

```
//a[contains(text(),'Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1')]/../following-sibling::td[last()]//input[@type='checkbox']
```

You are looking for `Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1`, instead, it is `Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1`

if this is unique `//a[contains(text(),'Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1')]` then the XPath provided by me should work.

Answer (score 1):

The element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to click() on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the *`elementToBeClickable()`* and you can use either of the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over):

- Using *xpath* and *index*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(., 'Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1')]//following::td[12]//input[starts-with(@id, 'ContentModify') and @type='checkbox']"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *last()*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr[@class='ContentRowOdd']/td[.//a[contains(., 'Samsung GALAXY Note 10.1')]]//following::td[last()]//input[starts-with(@id, 'ContentModify') and @type='checkbox']"))).click();
  ```

Comment: never hardcode numbers in XPath `td[12]` this is not a good practice.

Comment: @cruisepandey Please have a relook, it's not a number as such but an index with is inevitable when locating element with respect to some other element. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: if the UI dev adds one more `td` in between, then `td[12]` would not work. The HTML shared by OP `last()` seems more sensible. Now I see that you've modified your answer with `last(), it's all good now.

Comment: @cruisepandey _if the UI dev adds one more td in between_: None of my answer's are question specific. All are generalized answers which can benefit the broader audience. However answers are subjected to modification, please don't be suprised to see another new locator within a short while.